# How is POSIX nanosleep implemented on x86 Linux?

Tags: kernel, posix

How is [`nanosleep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) implemented on  x86 Linux?

The description states:

> `nanosleep()` suspends the execution of the calling thread until either at least the time specified in `*req` has elapsed, or the delivery of a signal that triggers the invocation of a handler in the calling thread or that terminates the process.

Let's say I want to sleep for `n` nanoseconds.

My initial assumption would be that execution is suspended with `HLT`. This suspends until the next 'external interrupt'. So, I will need to schedule an interrupt.

- How can I schedule an interrupt for `n` nanoseconds from now?
- How will my processor know to interrupt at that point -- e.g. will it check each cycle? If it checks each cycle, how is this any less resource-intensive than simply busy waiting with a loop?

Comment: Invalid initial assumption. HLT would halt the whole CPU, so no other process could be scheduled at all. HLT is not executable from user space. `nanosleep` and `clock_nanosleep` are kernel calls, and are accurate only to the granularity of the underlying hardware clock. The usual scheduling delays to the calling process also occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, `nanosleep` [relies on high-resolution timers](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/time/hrtimer.c#L2118). The [main sleep loop](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/time/hrtimer.c#L2035) loops over

- put the current task to sleep
- start a timer
- reschedule

as long as there’s no pending signal and the timer hasn’t expired (`t->task` becomes `NULL` when the timer expires), restarting if necessary (when a signal is handled before the timer expires).

The high-resolution timer provides the interrupt. Execution isn’t suspended using a CPU instruction such as `HLT`, because there are probably other tasks waiting to run while the task calling `nanosleep` sleeps.